# Feeds Xpath Parser

Tags: feeds

I'm using the Xpath parser module for my drupalsite, and now I want to pick a result from an XML that has a certain time. The XML parts looks like this

```
    <time from="2012-12-17T12:00:00" to="2012-12-17T18:00:00" period="2">
      <!-- Valid from 2012-12-17T12:00:00 to 2012-12-17T18:00:00 -->
      <symbol number="4" name="Cloudy" var="04"/>
      <precipitation value="0.6" minvalue="0.3" maxvalue="0.6"/>
      <!-- Valid at 2012-12-17T12:00:00 -->
      <windDirection deg="80.2" code="E" name="East"/>
      <windSpeed mps="3.2" name="Light breeze"/>
      <temperature unit="celsius" value="-2"/>
      <pressure unit="hPa" value="1014.3"/>
    </time>
    <time from="2012-12-17T12:00:00" to="2012-12-17T18:00:00" period="2">
      <!-- Valid from 2012-12-17T12:00:00 to 2012-12-17T18:00:00 -->
      <symbol number="4" name="Cloudy" var="04"/>
      <precipitation value="0.6" minvalue="0.3" maxvalue="0.6"/>
      <!-- Valid at 2012-12-17T12:00:00 -->
      <windDirection deg="80.2" code="E" name="East"/>
      <windSpeed mps="3.2" name="Light breeze"/>
      <temperature unit="celsius" value="-2"/>
      <pressure unit="hPa" value="1014.3"/>
    </time>
```

And now I want to pick the time with from=....12:00....

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/time/@from 
/time/@to
/time/@period
```